# Integrated terminal setup for msys mingw not working for build task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have managed to get the integrated terminal working with msys (bash) terminal using the following settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\msys64\\bin\\msys_shell.cmd",
"terminal.integrated.shellargs.windows": "-mingw64 -defterm -nostart",
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": "HOME": "${workspace Folder}"
```

And this works well.  I had to add the env "HOME" entry to get the sh to start in the correct home directory as it wouldn't work with (or with nothing at all):

"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"

Now I have run into another problem.  While the above settings work perfectly for a terminal window they fail for the build task. So I am forced to manually "make" from the integrated terminal window.

It fails with with error:

/d: /d: is a directory

My environment is Windows 10 msys64 mingw64.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. On their [help page](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558) for tasks.json they talk about the options fields in the settings.

VSCode uses the default shell for tasks unless you tell it not to. Additionally you'll have to pass your command to the resulting shell. I solved that using `-shell bash -c` so bash runs the command immediately.

The syntax is something like this:

```
"command": "make -j8",
"options": {
  "shell": {
    "executable": "C:\\msys2\\msys2_shell.cmd",
    "args": ["-defterm", "-mingw64", "-no-start", "-here", "-shell bash -c"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that with this setup extra command arguments were being dropped for some reason.

E.g, my command would be "make clean", but it would run as if only "make" was passed.

I managed so solve it by setting the command to "\"make clean\"", seems putting extra quotes in there made it work. Dunno if this was just somethis weird with my setup though.